# PHP include inside select element

Tags: php, html

Inside `list.php`, I have a huuuuge list of `<option>` elements all written correctly.
On `page.php`, I'm trying to use `<?php include ('path/to/list.php'); ?>` *inside* a `<select>` element. When the page loads, the select element is present but none of the options load in.

The full setup:

```
<select>
    <?php include('php/list.php'); ?>
</select>
```

And then list.php:

```
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
...
<option>Option 150</option>
```

**I understand** that text elements do not render inside select nodes, however shouldn't this work as intended?

**EDIT**
So after much deliberation and about an hour spent trying to figure out why simple PHP wasn't working, the answer is: make sure you're typing in the full path to your file. Keeping this question up so that future users can view a few different methods of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's impossibile considering your list.php has HTML (HTML gets automatically outputted leaving ob_* function). You have some errors elsewhere..

Try `require` so you can see a fatal error if it fails

Comment: I don't believe it's impossible - if he's not outputting anything from list.php then he'll get the behavior described.

Comment: The actual issue was that I was calling the wrong path. Geeze, feel like a moron... I guess I need to get some more sleep. I'll keep this question up for those who may have questions about alternate methods of doing this; marking 'yes123' as the answer because he's correct - *I* was the fatal error.

Comment: @yes123 - apologies for the downvote, I was wrong in my assumption.  If you want to edit your response I'll be able to remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?=file_get_contents('php/list.php')?>
```